# Dynamically generated QGLWidget in Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qglwidget

I would like to add a dynamic QGLWidget to the user interface of my application. By dynamic I mean that a certain parameter/variable will decide on which QGLWidget subclass to instantiate. Will that be possible to achieve in Qt Designer? Can I create for example an abstract class which I then inherit from to create say two concrete subclasses and promote a QWidget in the UI to the type of that abstract class?